# Orbeon 2017.2 CE & Glassfish - Builder & Runner "Error performing search"

Tags: glassfish, orbeon

I'm running Glassfish5 and the Orbeon 2017.2 CE deployment with no customizations, just the out-of-the-box wars. When I deploy those in Tomcat, everything works. I need to run it in Glassfish though. Deploying in Glassfish, I get the orbeon/home screen. When selecting and subsequently loading the Form Builder or Form Runner, the summary screens provide the error "Error performing search." If attempting to save a new form, "There was an error communicating with the database. Please contact the application administrator." I'm guessing the configuration is not using the built-in eXist DB? I can provide the error logs if needed.

Comment: also tried using Glassfish 4.2, same error

Comment: Yes, could you check if you can find any indication as to what went wrong in your `orbeon.log`? And if you can't, could you delete the file, restart the server, reproduce the problem, upload the `orbeon.log` somewhere, and link to it in a comment?

Comment: It might be useful to see the GlassFish server.log too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to the Glassfish and Postgresql DB configuration, since the eXist db is only for initial testing/demo purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to insert in the `properties-local.xml`

```
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.active" value="false"/>
```

Comment: sorry it took so long to get back and answer. I ended up just tracking down configuration setup for Glassfish and Postgresql, since that was the end goal.